# List of all possible openpyxl fill types?

Tags: python, openpyxl

Where can I find a list of all possible PatternFill fill types for openpyxl? The best I could do was

```
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
PatternFill(fill_type='diagonal_stripe')
```

to produce an error that lists them all out for me.

```
ValueError: Value must be one of {'gray0625', 'lightGrid', 'lightHorizontal', 'lightTrellis', 'lightVertical', 'darkUp', 'solid', 'darkVertical', 'mediumGray', 'darkTrellis', 'lightGray', 'darkGrid', 'darkHorizontal', 'gray125', 'lightUp', 'darkDown', 'darkGray', 'lightDown'}
```

This is information I was looking for! Where can I find this kind of thing in the documentation?

Comment: Interestingly, [`patternType` choices are documented](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.styles.fills.html#openpyxl.styles.fills.PatternFill.patternType), but `fill_type` is not. At a glance, they look like the same list that you show here in the error message.

Answer (score 2):

You can find it documented under the [`patternType`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.styles.fills.html#openpyxl.styles.fills.PatternFill.patternType) attribute of `PatternFill`.

I agree with myself; the documentation is not very helpful in showing you that `fill_type` is an alias for `patternType`:

> Aliases can be used when either the desired attribute name is not allowed or confusing in Python (eg. “type”) or a more descriptve name is desired (eg. “underline” for “u”)

FYI: It likewise appears that `start_color` and `end_color` are aliases for `fgColor` and `bgColor`, respectively. (Apparently you start coloring in the foreground and end in the background...?)

Comment: "I agree with myself" I'd be concerned if you didn't.